# Start a new Schedule Job by rest call in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

I am doing a spring boot project. Here is main method and a controller method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="nokia.quartz")
@EnableScheduling
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context =SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);     
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private SampleTask m_sampletask;

    @RequestMapping(value = "start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void start() throws Exception {              
        m_sampletask.work();
    }

}
```

And a Sample class

```
@Component
public class SampleTask {

    String cron_expression="0 0/1 * * * ?";

    public void work() {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

What the problem here is the rest call "/start" should make the SampleTask work() method a schedule job with the given cron expression when I am calling it from from rest endpoint "/start". Also I should be able to configure it at runtime with another rest endpoint as well as stop it..

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make use combination of `@EnableScheduling` annotation and `@Scheduled(cron= 0 0/1 * * * ?)`  for creating a scheduler in Spring boot. 
   Please add `@EnableScheduling` at starting of App Class and `@Scheduled` to the method which you want to run using cron.

PFB the useful link.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

2. You can try below option

   > ```
   > @Autowired     
   > TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
   > ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
   > @RequestMapping(value = "start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   > public void start() throws Exception { 
   >   scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(m_sampletask.work(), FIXED_RATE);
   >  }
   > ```

### Runnable Code of Nawaz:

```
@Component 
public class SampleTask implements Runnable { 
    String cron_expression="0 0/1 * * * ?"; 
    @Override public void run() { System.out.println("Hello"); } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahil .. How do you pass any arguments to the calling method... I made some changes in SampleTask and made it runnable to make compatible with your code..       <pre><code>@Component
public class SampleTask implements Runnable{

 String cron_expression="0 0/1 * * * ?";
 
 @Override
 public void run() {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  
 }
}</code></pre>

Comment: I have passed the parameters .. Thanks